# Hissing noise when clutch pressed [SUBARU WRX, manual]

Tags: noise, transmission, manual-transmission

Recently I started to notice right after cold start there is a hissing noise coming from the bottom of the car on the driver's side when clutch is pressed. The noise usually goes away after driving for a while. The sound is clearer to hear when the air is humid compared to when it's sunny outside.

I did some research on the internet and some suggest that there could be a leakage in the transmission system. Shifting gears and driving are completely normal and I've not experienced any difficulty yet.

What could be the problem here and should I bring it to a dealer to diagnose?

Comment: It could also be the first warning sign of a failing clutch release bearing. Get it checked out before something happens that causes a lot of collateral damage. A clutch failure can wreck the gearbox if you get really unlucky.

Comment: @alephzero Thanks for your advice! Just out of curiosity, if the bearing is failing, why would the sound go away after driving for a period of time? Normally, I would have the vehicle checked out but given what's going on outside, I'd like to fix it myself if possible.

Comment: Replace the release bearing and possible the clutch while it is apart.

Comment: @Will Clearances may change as different parts heat up at different rates. I once had the opposite situation, the clutch was silent unless the car was idling in traffic for a while in hot weather. The cause of that was definitely the release bearing. FWIW I don't know about the details of the US lockdown, but in the UK some of the national repair shop chains and main dealers still have functioning repair departments. After all, somebody needs to maintain vehicles for key workers who need them.